# DataTemplate does not work, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF, I have an application where I have defined a datatemplate for my custom type Person.
I am using this in a ContentControl but I only see type name of my type Person.
Here is the code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Person" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="_Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
                <Label Content="_Age:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" >

        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and....

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Person _person {get;set;} 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _person = new Person { Age = 30, Name = "David" };
            DataContext = _person;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button is clicked!!!");
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _age;
        private string _name;
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return _age;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _age)
                {
                    _age = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `x:Type` like `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">`?

Comment: As addition (explanation) to @dkozl comment. From MSDN `If the template is intended for object data, this property contains the type name of the data object (as a string). To refer to the type name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension. If the template is intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name. See the documentation remarks for details about specifying a non-default namespace for the XML element.`

Comment: @dkozl: thanks, it's working now, i was missing Type.